# 3D simulation software (e.g. for quadcopters)

Tags: 3d, simulation

On the weekend, myself and a friend want to make a [quadcopter](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadcopter) (aka quadrocopter) for something fun to do. However, we're wondering about things like weight/thrust ratios of different fan blades and motors etc. And we realised we'd like to create a basic model of a quadcopter in a 3D simulation software to test different efficiencies.

What software would be suitable for this?

I can't find anything after some Googling. We'd love to build many things besides quadcopters too in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are quite some Quadcopter kits on the market, and "how-to"s I don't think it is easy to create one from the scratch. Therefore I agree that first simulating the Quadcopter is a good start, although I am not sure until what detail you can simulate it (i.e. with the weights of the motors and rotors, etc).

You can use [ROS](http://quadcopter.bnash.com/using-ros-gazebo-simulator-with-arducopter/) (Robot Operating System) with the [Gazebo simulator](http://gazebosim.org/) as explained here: [Using ROS Gazebo simulator with ArduCopter](http://quadcopter.bnash.com/using-ros-gazebo-simulator-with-arducopter/). And see the tutorial [Using ROS/Gazebo Simulator with SIT](http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/using-rosgazebo-simulator-with-sitl/), or the [official Gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=get_started). Gazebo already has a large list of [models of objects and robots](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src), among which a [simple Quadrotor](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/e024fe922c810f468e2a7ab277750354465478cd/quadrotor/?at=default).
Furthermore [hector_quadrotor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) might be useful since it:

> contains packages related to modeling, control and simulation of quadrotor UAV systems

In another related [question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/blender-a-good-robotic-simulator-for-quadcopters-swarm-simulations) [v-rep](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/) was mentioned as simulator.
And in [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/6312/10041) the author refers to a simulator he made: [bettercopter](https://github.com/mkschreder/bettercopter).

Comment: That was all brilliant information for me to start off with. I'm off to go check it all out. Thanks heaps.